# Facebook audience network open ad in new window/tab

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-audience-network

I have integrated facebook audience netowrk ads to my mobile web app. But if an ad is clicked then it opens in the same window, is there anything to open the ad in new tab? 
below is the code I get from facebook

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.Event.subscribe(
            'ad.loaded',
            function(placementId) {
                console.log('Audience Network ad loaded');
                document.getElementById('ad_root').style.display = 'block';
            }
    );
    FB.Event.subscribe(
            'ad.error',
            function(errorCode, errorMessage, placementId) {
                console.log('Audience Network error (' + errorCode + ') ' + errorMessage);
            }
    );
};
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id))
        return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.ad.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div class="fb-ad" data-format="native" data-nativeadid="ad_root" data-placementid="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" data-testmode="false">
</div>
<div id="ad_root">
<a class="fbAdLink">
    <div class="fbAdMedia thirdPartyMediaClass"></div>
    <div class="fbAdTitle thirdPartyTitleClass"></div>
    <div class="fbAdBody thirdPartyBodyClass"></div>
    <div class="fbAdCallToAction thirdPartyCallToActionClass"></div>
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try adding `target="_blank`" to the link?

```
<a class="fbAdLink" target="_blank">
    <div class="fbAdMedia thirdPartyMediaClass"></div>
    <div class="fbAdTitle thirdPartyTitleClass"></div>
    <div class="fbAdBody thirdPartyBodyClass"></div>
    <div class="fbAdCallToAction thirdPartyCallToActionClass"></div>
</a>
```

Comment: no this does not work.. I have already tried it before posting this question